# Prevent echo line from AJAX response

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I want to prevent an echo from an AJAX response. I have 2 buttons and I need to enable and disable them using JS by AJAX responses. The JS code to enable/disable the HTML elements has been already written inside the PHP if condition of the AJAX URL Page. From AJAX I can display the results on `<span id="dupmsg"></span>`.
The result will be "Already Exists" and "Not Exist". I only want to display the message and enable/disable the buttons based on the condition. Here it's not working:

**Index Page in php:**

```
<h2>Enabling and Disabling text field using JavaScript</h2>

<form id="registration-form">
Enter your name: <input type="text" id="name">
</form>

<button onclick="disable()">Disable the text field</button>
<button onclick="enable()">Enable the text field</button>


    <p>Ajax Response is: <span id="dupmsg"></span></p>  

<script>
    function check_dup()
    {                       
    var barcode=$("#memb_barcode").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "ajax_attendance.php",
            data: {

                barcode: barcode

            },

            success: function(msg)
            {

                //alert(msg); // your message will come here. 
                    $('#dupmsg')
                    .css('color', 'red')
                    .html(msg)                                      
            },

                 error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
                     alert('Exception:', exception);
                 }
        })              
    }
</script>
```

**Ajax URL Page:**

```
<?php
$reg_no = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['reg_no']);
$barcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['barcode']);

$sql = "SELECT id from tblstudent  where reg_no = '$reg_no' && barcode like '$barcode' ";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$ecount = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($ecount!=0)
{
    printf("Already Exists");
    echo'   
          <script>
          function disable() {
              document.getElementById("name").disabled = true;
          }
          </script> ';                                
}
else
{
    printf("Not Exists");

    echo'
        <script>
        function enable() {
            document.getElementById("name").disabled = false;
        }
        </script>  ';   
}               
?>
```

The problem is that the JS written inside the PHP echo is reflecting back to `span id="dupmsg"` with AJAX response. I don't want to bring it in AJAX response. Please help.

Comment: Why are you echoing it if you don't want to put it into the span?

Comment: The PHP script should only echo what the JS client needs in the response.

Answer (score 1):

```
<h2>Enabling and Disabling text field using JavaScript</h2>

<form id="registration-form">
Enter your name: <input type="text" id="name">
</form>

<button id="disable" onclick="disable()">Disable the text field</button>
<button id="enable" onclick="enable()">Enable the text field</button>


    <p>Ajax Response is: <span id="dupmsg"></span></p>  

<script>
    function check_dup()
    {                       
    var barcode=$("#memb_barcode").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "ajax_attendance.php",
            data: {

                barcode: barcode

            },

            success: function(msg)
            {

                if(msg=='true'){
                    document.getElementById("name").disabled = true;
                    $("#disable").attr("disabled", true); // write the id of the button u want to hide
                    $('#dupmsg')
                    .css('color', 'red')
                    .html("Already Exists") 
                }
                else if(msg=='false')
                    {
                        document.getElementById("name").disabled = false;
                        $("#enable").attr("disabled", false); // write the id of the button u want to hide
                        $('#dupmsg')
                    .css('color', 'red')
                    .html("Not Exists")
                    }


            },

                 error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
                     alert('Exception:', exception);
                 }
        })              
    }

     function enable() {
            document.getElementById("name").disabled = false;
        }
    function disable() {
              document.getElementById("name").disabled = true;
          }
</script>




ajax_attendance.php
<?php
$reg_no = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['reg_no']);
$barcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['barcode']);

$sql = "SELECT id from tblstudent  where reg_no = '$reg_no' && barcode like '$barcode' ";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$ecount = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($ecount!=0)
{
    return true;

}
else
{
    return false;

}               
?>
```